# RSpec tests failing with 'unknown attribute'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, attr-accessible

I'm testing for attribute response in my model:

```
it { should respond_to(:password) }
it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }
```

These attributes aren't part of the database but simply declared in my model as `attr_accessible`. When I don't declare them and run my tests I get:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error:
  Can't mass-assign protected attributes: password, password_confirmation
```

But after I declare them I get:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:
  unknown attribute: password
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: you've chosen the wrong answer as correct =/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@8vius because you are following the tutorial, but not closely enough. 
You need to add the line:

```
has_secure_password
```

below
    attr_accessible :email, :name, :role, :password, :password_confirmation

this allows you to save the plain text password and password_confirmation into memory so that you can compare the strings and enforce equality before encrypting and saving into the DB. You don't want to persist the password in plain text on the db.

Comment: your answer should be the chosen one

Answer (score 2):

`attr_accessible` tells Rails you allow so called mass assignement on attributes.

But attributes must exist in db or you should create getter/setter, the easiest means is:

```
attr_accessor :password_confirmation, :password
```

Anyway, sounds weird you don't store the password.

Comment: I do store it but thats not the attribute, I'm following the tutorial http://ruby.railstutorial.org/

Comment: Just took a look at it, seems `attr_accessor` declaration is missing

Comment: Yeah, it is, it works now, he must have skipped it by mistake in the tutorial por some reason.

Comment: You see, this is one of those things that is not explained properly (I think) in most books and tutorials. Thank you for the answer! I did not know that attr_accessible will only work for variables that are already in the database. I thought it was a combined getter/setter for classes in Rails that was a bit of syntactic sugar!

Comment: @8vius read the other answer carefully so you understand what is really going on with that issue. I know it is already solved but checking the incorrect answer is not good for future visitors ;) In the tutorial you have a clear explanation about it: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users#sec-password_and_confirmation